# which lines to delete when trying to fix conflict errors in a git branch

Tags: git

I am trying to update a development branch with new changes made to the master branch.

So I did this command:

```
'git checkout master'
'git pull'
'git checkout NewCombatBranch'
'git rebase master'
```

And it said I had some conflicts.

I went to the git documentation to help me understand how to fix the conflicts.

But when viewing the conflicts in the affected file, I'm totally unsure what to do.

Here are the conflicts in the file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
function getShip(startSignal, isCaptialShip) {
    var isMotherShip = (startSignal) === "X1" ? true : false

    if (isCaptialShip) {
        return "war";
    } else (isMotherShip) {
        return "populate";
    } 
}

function isMotherShipSignal(gameTime) {
    if ((gameTime) === "0001-01-01T00:00:00-05:00") {
=======
function getShip(isDestroyed, startSignal, isCaptialShip) {
    var isMotherShip = (startSignal) === "0000X1" ? true : false
    
    if (isWarShip) {
        return "war";
    } else (isMotherShip) {
        return "populate";
    }
}

function isMotherShipSignal(gameTime) {
    if (new Date(gameTime).toLocaleTimeString('en-US') === "12:00:00 AM") {
>>>>>>> fixed battle change errors
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Looking at this, I'm not sure what to keep and what to discard.

I know I need the new changes in my master branch...but I am not sure what I'm really looking at.

Should I delete the ones that said HEAD?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add to the question the rebase command you typed?

Comment: @RomainValeri sure can...thanks!

Comment: Comparing the 2 tips of the branches does _not_ allow you to solve the conflict... you would be guessing, for the most part. We need to look at how the common ancestor looked (in a rebase it's not the common ancestor, but anyway). So, try this on the rebase command: `git -c merge.conflictStyle=diff3 rebase`

Comment: Or just `git checkout -m --conflict diff3 the/file` to get diff3's as a one-off.

Comment: @jthill I'm not sure what you mean.  What is diff3?  And for the/file do you mean the file that contains the actual conflict?  Thanks!

Comment: A conflict is two different sets of changes affecting overlapping/abutting lines, with the diff2 you're looking at you see the two different results but you can't see what the original was. diff3 shows you the original hunk too, so you can see what change each made from that

Comment: @jthill I did the command you said, but it just executed it.  Do I need to open the file again in an editor?

Comment: @jthill ok I found it...but it just shows me a bunch of 'ours', 'theirs', and base....

Comment: Make that file look like it should, that's what automerge couldn't figure out so it's showing you the hunks and letting you produce the right result.

Comment: @jthill  Thanks.  I did make the file look like it should by deleting stuff that shouldn't be there and adding stuff that was missing or not right. I then saved it. Did a commit -add to it. Then like the instructions say, I did git rebase --continue.  And then it just gave me the same conflict message on the same file like it did in the beginning.  I'm not sure what it wants me to do.

Comment: ... and you might get more conflicts as you are rebasing and the revisions being rebased touch on a section of code that was modified on the base branch..... so, it's business as usual. Fix conflicts, `git add blah; git rebase --continue`